# Event Bus and large data best practices

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, event-bus

I'm in the process of using an Event Bus, for all the various benefits.

I know that an Event Bus is just for passing small massage, as this is its core usage.

Are there any design patterns or architectural patterns for the Event Bus handling large data items, like images or videos?

Comment: You can store large data in a storage (Blob Storage / CosmosDb /...) and send a message with the storage-link to the Event Bus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architectural pattern is called Claim Check pattern.

Microsoft has documented this pattern with various options for implementation in Azure ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check)). The general pattern description is available [here](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use EventHubs for message passing mechanism in the architecture, However data storage should be either Cosmosdb/Blob storage. There are reference architecture available with [`Eventhubs/cosmosdb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/facilities-management-powered-by-mixed-reality-and-iot) which you can have a look